# KMPlayer - how to remove startup screen/iframe?

Tags: kmplayer

Does anybody know how to remove start-up iframe/screen that is shown whenever I start KMPlayer.

[image]

I have tried with Skins ->Logo ->Skin Default Logo, but with no luck.

Comment: This new "feature" is a real pain in the neck; I hope someone will have the answer, because I can't find how to remove it.

Answer (score 2):

Use your firewall to block KMPlayer internet acces.

Comment: blocking kmp at firewall will restrict the connection from kmp but it wont remove the startup screen

Answer (score 1):

just edit your hosts file, located in c:/windows/system32/drivers/etc/host and add the line 127.0.0.1 player.kmpmedia.net no sidebar will appear
Edit in Notepad, run Notepad as an administrator in order to save back the file